# UserFrosting installation - pages showing with no CSS

Tags: php, cloud9-ide, cloud9, userfrosting

I have just installed UserFrosting onto my project on Cloud 9 (c9.io). Everything has gone well apart from the fact that the pages appear with no CSS. Pages appear as plain text.

I have registered the master account (that registration page had CSS styling).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What is it showing in your browser console when it tries to load the external CSS resources?  404 error?

Comment: @alexw I completely forgot to check the console, my bad. It appears it is unable to load any CSS / JS because "'(url removed)' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script '(script name removed)'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Comment: Ah, ok.  So for some reason, the HTTPS redirect is not being applied to the URLs for your CSS and JS.  Are you just using the `.htaccess` that ships with UserFrosting, or do you have some extra custom rules?

Comment: @LouisC. go ahead and add your own answer to the question, mark it as solved, then we can upvote it.

Comment: @alexw Thanks for your help, I discovered what I needed in the .htaccess file. Answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to uncomment the following lines in the `.htaccess` that came with UserFrosting:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This forwards HTTP to HTTPS.